# base64.encode Not Encoding The whole File , Missing Parts file Encoding Flutter Dart ERROR

Tags: flutter, dart

i am using following code to encode PDF file to base 64

```
                File f = new File(_path);
//              String base64pdf = base64Encode(f.readAsBytesSync());
                String base64pdf = base64.encode(f.readAsBytesSync());
                String fileName = _fileName;
                print('base64pdf: '+base64pdf);
```

I tried to encode the pdf file on here: [encoding website](https://base64.guru/converter/encode/file)

the result from the website shows that the base64 encoder inside flutter(dart) is trimming a big section of the String Generated and give only little first part of it ?
how to solve that , is this related with byte type?

Comment: try `print('base64pdf length: ${base64pdf.length}');`, what do you see?

Comment: If you meant that the string may not printed at a whole, the response is no I have printed the binary value too and there is parts missed

Comment: so what is the length? does it match the length of the base64 you got from the website you mentioned? also what is the length of `f.readAsBytesSync()`?

Comment: No it doesn't match

Comment: `File(_path).openRead().transform(base64.encoder).listen((d) => print(d.length));` - whats the output of this?

Comment: I/flutter (20657): base64pdf length: 3776
I/flutter (20657): read asbyte sync length: 2830
I/flutter (20657): File(_path).openRead().transform(base64.encoder) : 3772

Comment: and what is the right number in your opinion? 3776? 3772? anything else?

Comment: i am sorry man but , the length of the website generated text is :" Your string is 3776 characters long."that mean the String is not printed as a whole
what should i do here?

Comment: i deleted the first two comments

Comment: to be clear now the printed text on website length is:3776 and the base64pdf length: 3776 but the print doesnt show the whole base64pdf 
what should i do to print the whole text of base64pdf ?

Comment: i tried this : print('base64pdf: '+base64pdf+" Endhere===>>");
the whole  Endhere===>> is not printed

Comment: `File(_path)
  .openRead()
  .transform(base64.encoder)
  .listen((d) => RegExp('.{1,80}').allMatches(d).forEach((m) => print(m[0])));`

Comment: yes this regular take every 80 chararcter and show it in a single line , yes it worked thanks ,

Answer (score 0):

```
RaisedButton(
 onPressed: () async {
 List<int> imageBytes = await sampleImage.readAsBytes();
 base64Image =  base64Encode(imageBytes);
 print(base64Image);},),


SizedBox(height: 30,),


Image.memory(base64Decode(base64Image)),
```

> [Base 64 code in my git hub repo](https://github.com/hardik584/Flutter-lunchbox/blob/master/base64.dart)